# hex to int python but get a letter in response

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is pretty well documented but I keep getting output that doesn't make sense. I have a hex value that looks like

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x86\xa0
```

but I get

```
 >>> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x86\xa0'.hex()
'00000000000186a0'
```

I am expecting a int or at least a readable number. I assume I am using the wrong function.

Advice?

Comment: Is `100000` the output that you're expecting? If so, I suggest looking into `int.from_bytes`. E.g., `int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x86\xa0', "big")` (gives `100000`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then try this

```
    hex_bytes = b'\x12\x34'
    integer= int.from_bytes(hex_bytes,byteorder='big')
    print(integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a base value of 16
For Example

```
    hex_string = "a1"
    integer = int(hex_string, 16)
    print(integer)
```

The output of this will be 161
Try this out

Comment: But if you try this with their input you will get an error: `invalid literal for int() with base 16`. They aren't trying to convert a hex-string, they are trying to convert a bytes literal. You seem to be trying to answer a question that wasn't asked.